# Bootstrap prefix issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a Chrome Extension which injects an modal Dialog to the page.
This is build with bootstrap. I need to prefix bootstrap css to not affect the style of the page. I tried the suggestions via less looks good but the dialog doesn't open.

Thanks for any hints

Comment: can i have the fiddle demo?

Comment: sure http://jsfiddle.net/madprocessor/MAvpe/4/